# Ignoring errors while parsing list of lists to dictionary to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

How to tell pandas to ignore incorrect dictionary items in list?

For case of simplicity, if I have case from 1st version solution from previous question:

```
L =[['Manufacturer: Hyundai',
  'Model: Tucson',
  'Mileage: 258000 km',
  'Registered: 07/2019'],
 ['Manufacturer: Mazda',
  'Model: 6',
  'Year: 2014',
  'Registered: 07/2019',
  'Comfort',
  'Safety']]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split(':') for y in x) for x in L])
print (df)
```

Second dict item have 2 last items missing values ('Comfort' and 'Safety') but they are also missing ":" therefore pandas is throwing :

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #5 has length 1; 2 is required
```

How to tell pandas to ignore these type of errors and proceed with parsing of list?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I read somewhere that it's desirable to link other question if it's related. Thank you both for great answers @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a little `if` condition.

```
pd.DataFrame([
    dict(y.split(':') for y in x if ':' in y) for x in L])

  Manufacturer     Mileage    Model Registered   Year
0      Hyundai   258000 km   Tucson    07/2019    NaN
1        Mazda         NaN        6    07/2019   2014
```

If you want to include those values as NaN, then change the `if` to an `if-else` inside the comprehension.

```
pd.DataFrame([
    dict(y.split(':') if ':' in y else (y, np.nan) for y in x) for x in L])


   Comfort Manufacturer     Mileage    Model Registered  Safety   Year
0      NaN      Hyundai   258000 km   Tucson    07/2019     NaN    NaN
1      NaN        Mazda         NaN        6    07/2019     NaN   2014
```

Answer (score 1):

If values with no `:` are keys is possible add `if-else`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split(':') if ':' in y else (y, np.nan) for y in x) for x in L])
print (df)
       Comfort Manufacturer     Mileage    Model Registered  Safety   Year
0      NaN      Hyundai   258000 km   Tucson    07/2019     NaN    NaN
1      NaN        Mazda         NaN        6    07/2019     NaN   2014
```

Comment: Hmm, the `if-else` is only necessary for this example, since "comfort"  and "safety" aren't actually in any of the rows.

Comment: @coldspeed - yes, agree, not 100% sure if understand if is necessary add value or removing